# How can i calculate depositedAmount0 and depositedAmount1 from given liquidity Uniswapv3

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

How can i calculate depositedAmount0 and depositedAmount1 from given liquidity Uniswapv3

[image]

Comment: You can't calculate that from liquidity alone, deposited token amounts is historical information that was recorder at the time of the deposit(s). The exception is when if you also know the price at the time of the deposit, and there was only one deposit. Then simply the liquidity-to-amounts formulas from the whitepaper, same as with any other amounts.

Comment: Thank you. So this data can only be fetched from Uniswapv3 GraphQl?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some working code to get data from position ID , it uses etherjs and bignumber (JSBI), but has all the base math

```
import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import * as fs from 'fs';

    // ERC20 json abi file
let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('ERC20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

    // V3 pool abi json file
let pool = fs.readFileSync('V3PairAbi.json');
const IUniswapV3PoolABI = JSON.parse(pool);

    // V3 factory abi json
let facto = fs.readFileSync('V3factory.json');
const IUniswapV3FactoryABI = JSON.parse(facto);

let NFT = fs.readFileSync('UniV3NFT.json');
const IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI = JSON.parse(NFT);

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<RPC_Key>")

    // V3 standard addresses (different for celo)
const factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";
const NFTmanager = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88";

async function getData(tokenID){
    let FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factory, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, provider);

    let NFTContract =  new ethers.Contract(NFTmanager, IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI, provider);
    let position = await NFTContract.positions(tokenID);
    
    let token0contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token0, ERC20, provider);
    let token1contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token1, ERC20, provider);
    let token0Decimal = await token0contract.decimals();
    let token1Decimal = await token1contract.decimals();
    
    let token0sym = await token0contract.symbol();
    let token1sym = await token1contract.symbol();
    
    let V3pool = await FactoryContract.getPool(position.token0, position.token1, position.fee);
    let poolContract = new ethers.Contract(V3pool, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

    let slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();

    
    let pairName = token0sym +"/"+ token1sym;
    
    let dict = {"SqrtX96" : slot0.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), "Pair": pairName, "T0d": token0Decimal, "T1d": token1Decimal, "tickLow": position.tickLower, "tickHigh": position.tickUpper, "liquidity": position.liquidity.toString()}

    return dict
}


const Q96 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(96));

function getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96){
    let tick = Math.floor(Math.log((sqrtPriceX96/Q96)**2)/Math.log(1.0001));
    return tick;
}

async function getTokenAmounts(liquidity,sqrtPriceX96,tickLow,tickHigh,token0Decimal,token1Decimal){
    let sqrtRatioA = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickLow).toFixed(18);
    let sqrtRatioB = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickHigh).toFixed(18);
    
    let currentTick = getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96);
    
    let currentRatio = Math.sqrt(1.0001**currentTick).toFixed(18);
    let amount0wei = 0;
    let amount1wei = 0;
    if(currentTick <= tickLow){
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA)/(sqrtRatioA*sqrtRatioB)));
    }
    if(currentTick > tickHigh){
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    if(currentTick >= tickLow && currentTick < tickHigh){ 
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-currentRatio)/(currentRatio*sqrtRatioB)));
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(currentRatio-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    
    let amount0Human = amount0wei/(10**token0Decimal);
    let amount1Human = amount1wei/(10**token1Decimal);

    console.log("Amount Token0 wei: "+amount0wei);
    console.log("Amount Token1 wei: "+amount1wei);
    console.log("Amount Token0 : "+amount0Human);
    console.log("Amount Token1 : "+amount1Human);
    return [amount0wei, amount1wei]
}

async function start(positionID){
    let data = await getData(positionID);
    let tokens = await getTokenAmounts(data.liquidity, data.SqrtX96, data.tickLow, data.tickHigh, data.T0d, data.T1d);
}
     Using Position ID 5
start(5)
```

Comment: Hello @Crypto_Rachel, thanks the sharing this snippet. I just wanted to know where did you find the math formulas for computing token 0/token 1 amounts ? Thanks

Comment: Very solid baseline. It worked, and mapped correctly with my Uniswap V3 positions. Thank you. This really needs to be upvoted more. I was surprised at how difficult this operation actually was in the uniswap v3 contracts. I recognize that the deposits are represented in terms of liquidity, but still - a convenience method in the SDK would have been nice.